# redirect using response from web api is not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've read several posts here, about that issue, but none of them have worked.
This is my JS:

```
    var urlBase = '/api/Login';


this.Login = function (userid, pwd) {
    return $http.post(urlBase,
        {
            params:
                {
                    username: userid,
                    password: pwd
                }
        }
  );

};
```

and this is my web api controller:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        return response;
```

I also tried it with GET.
I tracked the process using google chrome developer tools (network tab), and I saw the response with 'google.com', but the application wasn't redirected to google.com.
[image: this is what I saw]

Comment: Why would you expect the application to do anything?  You have no code telling it to load a different page, you are just submitting an ajax request and doing nothing with the response.

Comment: should I just use window.location on the response? what is the best practice for that case? because I could just return a string from the server and then do it

Comment: since it's angular, you would probably use `$window.location` and inject `$window` into your controller/service, but yeah, I would probably just return something like `{url: "http://www.google.com"}` and then `$window.location.href = response.url;`

Comment: then, in theory I could just return the string "google.com"?
what is the advantage here of using HttpResponseMessage and set its header's location to 'google.com'?

Comment: here I don't see any advantage to setting the header's location, if it were a normal http request it would redirect  the browser, but since it's ajax it doesn't make sense.  Just return a string or json and handle it yourself.

Comment: @Lichte how did you get around this